# Creating a website that tunnels to other sites?

Tags: html, web, proxy

I would like to create a webpage that basically just tunnels into whatever other site you enter.

So if I go to mysite.example.com/?Reddit.com it will go to Reddit and display it on my page. Basically it's like a proxy except I'm somewhere I can't change my browser's proxy settings, but would like to view blocked pages.

Mysite.example.com is unrestricted but Reddit.com is.

Answer (score 1):

You should host your site on a server which has no restrictions to the internet, then make sure you can connect to your server. Try using [Glype](https://www.glype.com/).

Comment: he's not hosting on a restricted server, but his boss restricts use of reddit.com I bet